# passing array values from controller to model for insert/update operations

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am receiving a payment transaction confirmation of a payment gateway using API as follows. But I'm not able to consume the response and insert in database.

My controller:

```
$transaction_id= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pay_id');
$api = new Api('ID', 'key');   
//getting object of transation
$payment = $api->payment->fetch($transaction_id);
//passing payment details to database
$this->Payment_model->set_payment($transaction_id,true);
```

Current structure of `$payment` array:

```
pay\Api\Payment Object ( [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => pay_BVzDNK3vsp4Owl [entity] => payment [amount] => 35400 [currency] => INR [status] => authorized [order_id] => ) )
```

My `pay_model.php`:

```
  public function set_payment($payment,$first)
  {
      $data = array(
          'id' => $id,
          'entity' => $entity,
          'amount' => $amount,
          'currency' => $currency,
          'status' => $status,
          'order_id' => $order_id,
          'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
      );
      if ($first == TRUE) {
          //print_r($data);
          //  echo "breakpoint--i am in set user model id 0";
          return $this->db->insert('payments', $data);
      } else {
          //echo "breakpoint--i am in set user model id not 0";
          $this->db->where('id', $id);
          return $this->db->update('payments', $data);
      }
  }
```

**Issue** :  My $data array always receiving NULL values. How to consume the data I'm receiving here and pass to model for insert/update operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `$data` array are not define in the function scope (which gives you NULL value).

You have 2 errors. First is sending the right data to `set_payment` function:

```
$payment = $api->payment->fetch($transaction_id);
$this->Payment_model->set_payment($transaction_id,true);
```

I think the second line should be:

```
$this->Payment_model->set_payment($payment,true);
```

As sending the `$payment` and not the `$transaction_id`.

Second error is when using the data in `set_payment` function. When creating `$data` you should use it as:

```
'id' => $payment['id'], //and no just $id 
'entity' => $payment['entity'],//and no just $entity as those var not exist in this scope
// and so on...
```

Comment: Thanks resolved. transaction_id passing was a typo, but main assumption was i thought those variables will be within the scope, like we pass $data array to a view from controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in `set_payment()`:

your data array should look like:

```
 $data = array(
        'id' => $payment['id'],
        'entity' => $payment['entity'],
        'amount' => $payment['amount'],
        'currency' => $payment['currency'],
        'status' => $payment['status'],
        'order_id' => $payment['order_id'],
        'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```